# How to divide all columns by one column in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to divide all columns in a table by one of them? There are 168 of them so I'd rather not write column2/column1, column3/column1, etc.

Comment: simplest answer is to write a code that first gets the list of columns (INFORMATION_SCHEMA will help here); then iterates over the list (STORED PROCEDURE will help here) and generates the code that you want. Lastly run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Suggested by @Aishwary, you can write a script to get the list of columns using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#syntax) and then iterate over the list of columns to get the desired result.